# Help with writing a permutation in a symmetric group as a product of disjoint cycles

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

[image: image of the problem]

I don't follow how the step from the product of permutations to the two-line notation is done. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product is taken right to left. If $f=(2467)$, $g=(12365)$, and $h=(1375)$, then each element gets fed into the product like so:

\begin{align}
1&\stackrel{f}{\mapsto}1\stackrel{g}{\mapsto}2\stackrel{h}{\mapsto}2 \\
2&\stackrel{f}{\mapsto}4\stackrel{g}{\mapsto}4\stackrel{h}{\mapsto}4 \\
3&\stackrel{f}{\mapsto}3\stackrel{g}{\mapsto}6\stackrel{h}{\mapsto}6 \\
&\vdots
\end{align}

Can you continue from here?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I get it now!

Comment: You're welcome, @Sinnner! After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: And since your answer also deserves an upvote, +1.

Comment: Thank you, @DietrichBurde. I've already upvoted your answer $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1):

Apply the permutation $(1375)(12365)(2467)$ on the LHS, say, to the digit $1$. Then $(2467)$ fixes it, and then $(12365)$ sends it to $2$, where it stays under $(1375)$. So $1$ is mapped to $2$ under $(1375)(12365)(2467)$. And so on with the other digits. The result is $(124)(365)$.